# Disable URL encoding inside an HTTP request

Tags: perl, http, url, request, urlencode

I'm writing a small perl tool which should help me to speed up some processes during a blind SQL injection attack (it's an ethical tool. it's my job).

My script manages HTTP requests **already** url-encoded with hex values (%xx).
Therefore, my request is encoded twice when I use `HTTP::Request` to send it to the web browser.

I use this kind of code:

```
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $httpreq = new HTTP::Request GET => 'http://192.168.0.1/lab/sqli.php?id=1%20and%20(select%20ascii(substring(user,3,1))%20from%20mysql.user%20limit%201)>100%23';
my $res = $ua->request($httpreq)
```

How can I disable the perl URL encoding inside my request?

Answer (score 5):

HTTP::Request does not modify the provided URL.

Any URL encoding must be done before the URL is assembled — it's actually URL components that get encoded — so HTTP::Request expects the encoding to already be done.

```
>perl -MHTTP::Request -e"print HTTP::Request->new(GET => 'http://192.168.0.1/lab/sqli.php?id=1%20and%20(select%20ascii(substring(user,3,1))%20from%20mysql.user%20limit%201)>100%23')->as_string;"
GET http://192.168.0.1/lab/sqli.php?id=1%20and%20(select%20ascii(substring(user,3,1))%20from%20mysql.user%20limit%201)%3E100%23
```

Comment: @user755743, What I said isn't quite true. If you look carefully at the output, you'll see that HTTP::Request encoded ">". It did so because ">" isn't allowed in urls. It is well within HTTP::Request's rights to do so, and doing so didn't result in any double-encoding.

Comment: Hi, Indeed. I'm wrong. there is no double encoding (I should sleep  a bit more).